# how to point to char *argv[] in main?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, program-entry-point

In c++ I've got a main function with

```
  int argc, char * argv[]
```

I need to access the data in `argv[]` (i.e the arguments) in another function.

I am going to declare a global variable, a pointer to the `char **argv`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Just pass it as a parameter to this second function...

Comment: ... or just pass individual args, such as `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, etc as individual `const char *` parameters as needed.

Comment: Once you are inside main char *argv[] is just like any other variable you create. You can pass to another functions or even alter the content, etc.

Comment: How would I do that? How do I pass char * argv[] to the function?

Comment: declare the prototype as `function(char **, some-other types)` and use it as `function(argv, some-other variable)`

Answer (score 12):

In C++, usually* the best way to handle `argv` is this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);
}
```

Now you have `args`, a correctly constructed `std::vector` holding each element of `argv` as a `std::string`. No ugly C-style `const char*` in sight.

Then you can just pass this vector or some of its elements as you need.

<sub>* It carries the memory & time overhead of dynamically allocating one copy of each `argv` string. But for the vast majority of programs, command-line handling is not performance-critical and the increased maintainability and robustness is well worth it.</sub>

Comment: Assuming that "best" means most readable and most maintainable, and not "least amount of memory allocated on the heap". You are making a local hard copy, consuming more than twice the amount of needed memory, just for the sake of increasing source code readability.

Comment: @Lundin I'd say it's primarily increasing maintainability; source code readability comes second. And maintainability is one of the most important qualities of code. Yes, there are exceptions of performance-critical code, but command-line handling is likely not one of them. I'd guess often the allocation overhead will be topped by the string processing anyway. But I'm not dismissing your point; I'll weaken the wording slightly.

Answer (score 6):

Global variables should be avoided and you should prefer passing arguments. Anyway, you can just use:

```
char **global_argv = NULL;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    ...
    global_argv = argv;
    ...
}
```

A better way would be:

```
void my_fun1(int argc, char **argv);  // Passing all the program arguments
void my_fun2(char *arg);              // Passing just the one you need

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    ...
    my_fun1(argc, argv);
    my_fun2(argv[3]);                 // Supposing you need the 3rd parameter (fourth on argv)
    ...
}
```

Comment: There is never any reason to use global variables. If you can't pass it as parameter, for some odd reason unknown, then at least declare `global_argv` as `static`.